# R code to test the difference between coefficients of regressors from one panel regression

Tags: r, panel, chi-squared, plm, regression-testing

I am trying to compare two [regression](/questions/tagged/regression) coefficient from the same panel regression used over two different time periods in order to confirm the statistical significance of difference. Therefore, running my panel regression first with observations over 2007-2009, I get an estimate of one coefficient I am interested in to compare with the estimate of the same coefficient obtained from the same panel model applied over the period 2010-2017.

Based on [R code to test the difference between coefficients of regressors from one regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774582/r-code-to-test-the-difference-between-coefficients-of-regressors-from-one-regres), I tried to compute a likelihood ratio test. In the linked discussion, they use a simple linear equation. If I use the same commands in R than described in the answer, I get results based on a [chi-squared](/questions/tagged/chi-squared) distribution and I don't understand if and how I can interpret that or not.

In [r](/questions/tagged/r), I did the following:

```
linearHypothesis(reg.pannel.recession.fe, "Exp_Fri=0.311576")
```

where `reg.pannel.recession.fe` is the panel regression over the period 2007-2009, `Exp_Fri` is the coefficient of this regression I want to compare, `0.311576` is the estimated coefficient over the period 2010-2017.

I get the following results using `linearHypothesis()`:

[image: Results Likelihood ratio test]

How can I interpret that? Should I use another function as it is [plm](/questions/tagged/plm) objects?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a F test in that example because as stated in the vignette:

> The method for "lm" objects calls the default method, but it changes
>   the 
>       default test to "F" [...]

You can also set the test to F, but basically linearHypothesis works whenever the standard error of the coefficient can be estimated from the variance-covariance matrix, as also said in the vignette:

> The default method will work with any model
>    object for which the coefficient vector can be retrieved by ‘coef’
>        and the coefficient-covariance matrix by ‘vcov’ (otherwise the
>        argument ‘vcov.’ has to be set explicitly)

So using an example from the package:

```
library(plm)

data(Grunfeld)
wi <- plm(inv ~ value + capital,
data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")

linearHypothesis(wi,"capital=0.3",test="F")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
capital = 0.3

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: inv ~ value + capital

  Res.Df Df      F  Pr(>F)  
1    170                    
2    169  1 6.4986 0.01169 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

linearHypothesis(wi,"capital=0.3")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
capital = 0.3

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: inv ~ value + capital

  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1    170                       
2    169  1 6.4986     0.0108 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

And you can also use a t.test:

```
tested_value = 0.3
BETA = coefficients(wi)["capital"]
SE = coefficients(summary(wi))["capital",2]
tstat =  (BETA- tested_value)/SE
pvalue = as.numeric(2*pt(-tstat,wi$df.residual))
pvalue
[1] 0.01168515
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I managed to compute the F-test and t.test. I am a bit confused with the results. How would you interpret the results of your example ? Can you reject that capital =0.3 or not ?

Comment: do you mean that alpha = Pr(>F) (in your example 0.01169)? Therefore, you would reject capital = 0.3 as it is lower than 0.05. Which data would you plot? All of my independent variables are dummies capturing one day effect on the dependent variables.

Comment: sorry i meant if alpha = 0.05, you would reject the null hypothesis that capital = 0.3. yes you got it right.  you can try using http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/ or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggiraphExtra/vignettes/ggPredict.html to explore your data...

Comment: I don't know what your data is like and these are the things you needa thing about before  doing a statistical test. For my example above, i would plot the regression line and the data points and see how much confidence it is not 0.3 etc

Comment: Last thing, have I answered your very question?